# link:www.example.com returns 0 results

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

My website returns 0 results for **link:www.example.com** why it not showing any results ?
Is it because of all backlinks are low quality or what ? but In Google webmastertools "Links to Your Site" section it shows the link count. Please suggest me why it not returning any results. And I set my preferred domain to www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

> If you’re not seeing expected link data for a site, it may be that your site is indexed under a different host name. For example, if you're looking for links to http://www.example.com, make sure that you’ve added http://example.com to your account, and then check the data for that site. (Google recommends setting a preferred domain.)
>   If you use Google Analytics to track site data, you can link your site to an Analytics profile created using the same Google Account. When you link your site to an Analytics profile, you'll be able to quickly access the Referring Sites report directly from Webmaster Tools.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en

Comment: I set my preferred domain to www.example.com and I know this already!

Answer (score 1):

The link: command on Google does not give accurate results sometime. Try using Yahoo Site Explorer. It has some great features that I use regularly to track backlinks. With the site: command you get a fairly comprehensive list of the backlinks to your site compared to other online tools offering this service. You can also use the "link:" command for page analysis or "linkdomain:" for domain backlink analysis.

Yahoo Site Explorer also allows you to explore the backlinks of any site linking to yours by using the ‘Explore URL’ option, which can be really helpful.

I know of at least few sites that have links to this site yet when i do link:www.example.com, it returns no results in google, but shows all in msn/yahoo.